# Angular mat-card with bad view

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, grid

I have a series of `mat-cards` on a screen where they are dynamic in size, and they look beautiful that way

[image: My cards misaligned]

The problem is that each `mat-card` has a totally different set of items, making the *size/width* of the card dynamic, and consequently misaligned.

What I want is perhaps a little complicated, because, I need:

1. All of them to have a fixed size
2. Be perfectly aligned in relation to others
3. Respect the responsiveness in various devices
4. Items inside the card can't lose their composure with each other, that is (Text size, item position, icon size, etc.)

What solution or path can I use to fix this?

This is the **HTML** component that groups all the cards

```
<app-layout pageTitle="Configurações Fiscais">
  <section class="content">
    <app-addition-fiscal-config
      *ngIf="canAccessAdditionFiscalConfig()"
    ></app-addition-fiscal-config>
    <app-ibpt-fiscal-config>
    </app-ibpt-fiscal-config>
    <app-crt-fiscal-config> 
    </app-crt-fiscal-config>
    <app-nfse-fiscal-settings>
    </app-nfse-fiscal-settings>
    <app-ecnpj-config *ngIf="canAccessEcnpjConfig()"></app-ecnpj-config>
  </section>
</app-layout>
```

And its **CSS**

```
:host {
  section.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    & > * {
      flex: 1;
      flex-basis: 30%;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, a **HTML** example of one of these cards

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <div matCardAvatar class="icon-avatar primary-bg"><mat-icon>attach_money</mat-icon></div>
      <mat-card-title>Regime Tributário</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>
        Informe o regime tributário da sua empresa, podendo ser Simples Nacional, Lucro Presumido ou Lucro Real
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <app-data-selector display="description"
        label="Regime tributário"
        [repository]="crtFiscalRepository"
        [value]="value"
        (valueChange)="onFiscalCrtChange($event)"
      ></app-data-selector>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```